# How to get the longest word and the most frequent word starting with a specific letter?

Tags: command-line, bash, text-processing, pipe

Given a list of words and their count like this:

```
2 you
1 polka
2 dress
3 are
4 world
```

I would like to write 2 Bash piped commands which will give me:

1. The **longest** word starting with the letter 'a'
2. The **most frequent** word that starts with 'a'.

I was thinking to do it with `sed` `grep ^a` but I don't know how to write the rest of the piped command.

Comment: Again homework?

Comment: No. This is for my own project Im doing.

Comment: Ok, close vote removed :)

Comment: If it's not homework I assume using a pipe is not a requirement.

Comment: It is. Its a challenge between me and my co-worker, and this was one of the requirements.

Comment: I believe this is one of these rare occasions `bash` *is* off-topic here. Strictly programmatic question, nothing to do with administrating anything.

Answer (score 4):

To get the longest word, we can use `awk`'s `length` function. Then sort, then `head` and `cut` to get the right line and field.

```
awk '$2~/^a/ {print length($2), $2}' file | sort -k1 | head -1 | cut -d" " -f1
```

To get the most frequent A-word, a `sort` and `awk`:

```
sort -k1 file | awk '$2~/^a/ {print $2; exit}'
```

In real life I'd probably avoid piping things around so much. I'd probably do each in a single `awk`. Hard to say whether they'd actually perform faster though. `awk` is flexible but not that fast.

```
awk 'BEGIN{lc=0;lw=""} $2~/^a/ {l=length($2); if (l>lc){lc=l;lw=$2}} END{print lw}' file
awk 'BEGIN{fc=0;fw=""} $2~/^a/ {if ($1>fc){fc=$1;fw=$2}} END{print fw}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution without the requirement of using a pipe using AWK:

```
awk '$2~/^a/{if(length($2)>length(x))x=$2}END{print x}' in
awk '$2~/^a/{if($1>x[0]){x[0]=$1;x[1]=$2}}END{print x[1]}' in
```

Using Perl:

```
perl -lane '$F[1]=~/^a/||next;if(length($F[1])>length($x)){$x=$F[1]};END{print($x)}' in
perl -lane '$F[1]=~/^a/||next;if($F[0]>$x[0]){$x[0]=$F[0];$x[1]=$F[1]};END{print($x[1])}' in
```

```
% cat in
2 you
1 polka 
2 dress
3 are
4 world
1 abcd
4 abc
% awk '$2~/^a/{if(length($2)>length(x))x=$2}END{print x}' in
abcd
% awk '$2~/^a/{if($1>x[0]){x[0]=$1;x[1]=$2}}END{print x[1]}' in
abc
% perl -lane '$F[1]=~/^a/||next;if(length($F[1])>length($x)){$x=$F[1]};END{print($x)}' in
abcd
% perl -lane '$F[1]=~/^a/||next;if($F[0]>$x[0]){$x[0]=$F[0];$x[1]=$F[1]};END{print($x[1])}' in
abc
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the file is `foo`:

- The longest word with `a`

  ```
  % awk '$2 ~ /^a/ {print length($2),$2}' foo | sort | tail -n1
  3 are
  ```
- The most frequent word with `a`

  ```
  % awk '$2 ~ /^a/ {print $1,$2}' foo | sort | tail -n1
  3 are
  ```

On the other hand, why necessarily pipes? It's an absurd requirement.